# How to delete a file that is "being used by a program" but is not locked yet still doesn't delete

Tags: windows-10, file-management

I'm trying to delete a driver that is giving me issues with some games, I've tried LockHunter, System Monitor, Unlocker, Proccess Explorer but either none of them can delete it nor can they find what program is using the file, can I get some help?

Comment: What is the "driver" for? Have you uninstalled the device from device manager?

Comment: It doesn't let me uninstall from device manager

Answer (score 0):

Run Ubuntu live from a usb stick, find the file and delete it.
This video could help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6L6ovxxVuk